# Clearance of Text from UIimage

Tags: objective-c, ios, ocr

In my app i am trying to get the text from captured image. I am using the lib Tesseract for the conversion process. I am able to convert the captured image to text but the problem is the text at the right and left ends are seems to be a broke characters. Following is the image which sows the image which i have captured,
[image]

The captured image in the left and right end seems to be broken as in the following figure,
[image]

How to get all this text to be in perfect, when i was searching through google i found an app doing the same process. Additionally they were cleaning the captured image as in the following figure,
[image]

How can i clean the images like this?.